# Toggle external display under Wayland

Tags: gnu-screen, gnome3, display, wayland

Under X I had a xrandr command that would disable the external display or, if it was disabled, enable it and set it as the main/default display.

Is there anyway to achieve similar functionality under Wayland? I'm using the latest Gnome Shell.